# How To add nest Table in html?

Tags: html

Nest Table i.e. Table under Table. I have tried many time using many attributes but I am not getting what I want.
Please tell me here attributes how to do this. Thanks

Comment: Please provide us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>First cell in first table. The cell to the right has the second table in it.</td>
    <td>

      <table>
        <tr><td>nested table</td></tr>
        <tr><td>nested table</td></tr>
      </table>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```